# Multiple Local Schemas for XML Files

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XML and I need to import an XML file into Access or Excel 2010.

There are multiple Schemas that the file needs to refer to. This is what I have so far and it's not working. Can someone point me in the right direction please or am I completely wrong??

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.dcsf.gov.uk/schemas/cbds" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:SchemaLocation="File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Schemas\SC13-CBDS-Standard-Header.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Schemas\SC13-Spring-PupilModule.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Schemas\SC13-Spring-SchoolModule.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Schemas\SchoolCensus13-Spring.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Includes\bs7666.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Includes\EstabNoType.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Includes\LEAtype.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Includes\PeopleTypes.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Includes\PupilTypes.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Includes\SC_Address_Structure.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Includes\UPNtype.XSD
        File:\\ecsdcen2\Vol1\Groups\PIMD\Projects\ICYP%Projects\ICYP%-%School%Census\2013\January%2013\Source\School%Census\Includes\YearTypes.XSD">
    <Message>
     <Name>School Census</Name>
    <Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here.

- Your XML is not well formed, so it's impossible to know for sure what you intend the element structure of the document to be.  You have no end-tag for `xs:schema`, and you have an end-tag but no start-tag for `header`.

  Also, you use but do not bind the namespace prefix `xsi`; that prefix is conventionally bound to the XSD 'instance' namespace.  If that's the binding you want (it almost surely is), you want to add the following namespace declaration to your document's root element.

  ```
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  ```
- The `xs:schema` element is used to define components of schemas -- not to attach schema information to normal XML instances.  It's defined by the XSD specification, and neither `Message` nor `header` is among the children of any valid xs:schema element.
- The linkage between XML instance and schema can be expressed using the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute (note spelling!). is  used to specify, for a given XML element, where schemas can be found for the namespaces used within that element.
- The value of `xsi:schemaLocation` is a sequence of (namespace-name, schema-document-URI) pairs; your current value appears to be just a list of file-system paths to schema documents, none of them actually URIs.
- Also, the usual practice is for one top-level schema document for a namespace -- a driver file -- to refer (directly or indirectly) to all the others for that namespace.  Your `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute should point to that driver file, not to the other schema documents for the namespace.  So I'd expect something like this in your XML input:

  ```
  <header xmlns="http://www.dcsf.gov.uk/schemas/cbds" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:SchemaLocation="http://www.dcsf.gov.uk/schemas/cbds 
      file:///ecsdcen2/Vol1/Groups/PIMD/Projects/ICYP%20Projects/ICYP%20-%20School%20Census/2013/January%202013/Source/School%20Census/Schemas/cbds-driver.xsd">
    ...
  </header>
  ```

If your goal is to get the data our of XML and into some other form as fast as you can, then getting all these details of XML and XSD correct (just in order to get the data OUT of XML) is likely to be a bit tedious; I'd find a local XML / XSD expert and ply them with free drinks until they agree to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have contacted the DfE to see if there is anyone there to help me. There is no obvious driver xsd so I willl try and get hold of the guy who built it.